# CSS: Div Placement

Tags: html, css

I have a simple 4 block div that I'm trying to do.  It looks like this:

[image]

But I can't figure out a way to do it.  Some things that I'm trying to achieve:

1 and 4 need to be fixed.  When I scroll down, they should remain in place while 2 and 3 move accordingly.

I strictly want 2 and 3 to be within the boundaries of 1 and 4, not underneath it, this is the part where I'm having trouble doing, trying to figure out floats  and position.

Thanks

Comment: `position:relative;` on their parent Node. You have to get the height of 1 and 4, and the width of at least 1 so you can set `position:absolute;` on 2 and 3, and `position:fixed;` on 1 and 4.

Comment: I thought about that too but if I do that, depending on the size of the screen, there could be gaps in between 1 and 2 and 2 and 4.  I'd rather have it so no matter the browser size, they are touching border to border.

Comment: Please include relevant code in the question. Show us your most successful attempt so far.

Comment: There are plenty of high point questions without actual code.  I think my explanation was explanatory enough.  Sure, it'd be helpful to have it but it doesn't make the question any less clear or irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help

```css
html,body{height:100vh;}
.wrap{width:100%;height:100vh;position:relative;}


.left,.right{width:200px;height:100vh;}
.center,.bodywrap{height:100vh;}
.left{float:left;position:fixed;}
.center{margin-left:200px; margin-right:191px;}
.right{position:fixed;right:0;}

.left{background-color:#aaa;}
.right{background-color:#ccc;}
.center{background-color:#444;}
.head{background-color:#777;}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
    
    <div class='bodywrap'>
        <div class='left'>left</div>
        <div class='right'>right</div>
        <div class='center'>center center center center center center center center center center center center ... blah</div>
        <div class='center'>center center center center center center center center center center center center ... blah</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```